# redshift can not find geoclude2, after ubuntu 17 update

Tags: redshift

As i said in the topic, i got problem with geoclude.

I got:

```
unable to start GeoClude client: 
GDBus.Error.....AccessDenied:Geolocation disabled for UID 1000.
```

I also install fluxgui then, but even when it works, it doesn't change anything with the screen colours or contrast.

In /usr/share/gtk-doc/html/ i think i should have /geoclue directory, so i could edit .config file but there is just totem and no geoclude. Before system update everything was working fine.

Comment: Try this on terminal `sudo apt-get install geoclue-2.0`.

Comment: I already have the newest version, so it have to something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two Complementary solutions:

**1:** Edit GeoClue's config to allow redshift

Append the following lines to `/etc/geoclue/geoclue.conf` by running:

`sudo nano /etc/geoclue/geoclue.conf`

```
[redshift]
allowed=true
system=false
users=
```

**2:** Edit or create RedShift's config with manual options.

Example of a manual config, for Copenhagen, Denmark. See [Redshift homepage](http://jonls.dk/redshift/) for an additional config example. Change the latitude and longitude for you location.
`nano ~/.config/redshift.conf`

```
[redshift]
temp-day=6500
temp-night=3700
location-provider=manual

[manual]
lat=55.7
lon=12.6
```

**To Test**

In a terminal run `kill $(pgrep '[r]edshift*') && redshift -t 3600:3600` to kill the current instances and run redshift at 3600k temp. Over a few seconds the screen should adjust. If this works <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> to interrupt the current redshift instance. Edit the redshift config to your desired settings. Restart redshift with the new config by running `redshift-gtk & disown` in a terminal.

Comment: It helps by getting redshift works, but it is in 'off' mode in main options all the time and it imposible to turn in on, even when it is enabled in redshift choices.